# Failed to download metadata for repo 'updates-modular'

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

Today when I want to update my packages I got this error and I don't know what should I do to solve it

```
[root@fedora etc]# sudo dnf update
Fedora Modular 34 - x86_64 - Updates                     26 kB/s | 163 kB     00:06
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'updates-modular':
  - Zchunk error: Unable to find multipart download range

Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'updates-modular': Yum repo downloading error: Downloading error: Unable to initialize zchunk file repodata/13c5b8a8c503886539ad8883ea9efbbc3ac837b6ffa4570e63b829a2d4da1617-primary.xml.zck: Unable to set zchunk file descriptor for repodata/13c5b8a8c503886539ad8883ea9efbbc3ac837b6ffa4570e63b829a2d4da1617-primary.xml.zck: Unable to find multipart download range
```

I didn't find anything effective for solving this in my searches.
I've already test `sudo dnf clean all && sudo dnf update` 
sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: I came across this problem today. The fix was to append the line ```zchunk = False```  to ```/etc/dnf/dnf.conf``` and then run ```sudo dnf update``` again. https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/errors-during-downloading-metadata-for-repository-fedora/5275/9